# AWS Lightsail + Bitnami WordPress - Changed DNS to Cloudfare - Giving too many redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, dns-zone, redirection, bitnami

I have setup a WordPress website in AWS Lightsail (uses the Bitnami Wordpress). And I used the `bncert-tool` using the command `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool` to install the SSL.

I have forced www version to be used and and also the SSL was installed for the www and non-www domain using the above tool. DNS was managed within the Lightsail control panel's `Domain & DNS` section.

Then I decided to move to the Cloudfare to manage the DNS. So copied the DNS records to Cloudfare and update the nameserver of the domain name to point to the Cloudfare. And removed the DNS Zone I created in the `Domain & DNS` section of the Ligthsail instance.

But now whenever I try to access the domain, it shows an "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error message. And the site is not accessible as it continue the redirections.

Could this be because of the SSL installed using `bncert-tool` ? Any solutions to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure, since you haven't shared your domain or the DNS entries you've made. I do know it's fiddly, I've had similar things happen in the past.

There's a Wordpress Plugin called "[Cloudflare Flexible SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/)" which may help, and specifically mentions a redirect loop. There's also another "[CloudFlare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/third-party-software/content-management-system-cms/using-the-cloudflare-plugin-with-wordpress/)" plugin which I don't think will help with this but is worth considering using.

There's [a guide you could read through](https://www.icontrolwp.com/blog/enabling-cloudflares-universal-flexible-ssl-wordpress-without-infinite-redirect-loops/?utm_source=in-plugin&utm_medium=plugin-readme&utm_content=wordpress.org&utm_campaign=cloudflare-flexible-ssl-plugin), I can't vouch for it, it was linked from the first plugin.

Comment: Thank you......